# Sublime Text 2 shortcut line substitution

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor, sublimetext2

Excuse me for the non-informative title. Just can't shortly describe what I want within one question.

Okay, let's say we have two lines in our text file. The cursor is somewhere in the 1st line (the example shows cursor position):

```
SO helps| people
People like SO
```

What I want is to substitute the first line with an empty line or with another line and cursor should be at the start of this empty line.

I tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>   +<kbd>L</kbd> and type the "new line". But <kbd>CTRL</kbd>   +<kbd>L</kbd> expands selection to the line + \n and that causes this result (the example shows cursor position):

```
new line|People like SO
```

If the cursor is at the begining of the line, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>   +<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> works perfect. But how can do the same when the cursor is not at the begining (without pressing   <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  , arrows and using mouse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of **Ctrl + K + K** at the beginning of a line when the cursor is somewhere in the line is : **Ctrl + Shift + K**

Here:

```
first line with text
second line| with other text
third line with another text
```

-> **Ctrl + Shift + K** :

```
first line with text
|third line with another text
```

## EDIT

Since it is requested that the result should be:

```
first line
|
third line
```

You could either do what is written above and press *ENTER* or go to *`Packages/Delete Line.sublime-macro`* and replace the file with the following code:

```
[
    {"command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "line"}},
    {"command": "add_to_kill_ring", "args": {"forward": true}},
    {"command": "left_delete"},
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n"}},
    {"command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false}}
]
```

Comment: I want the result to be `firstline..., empty line with cursor, third line`

Comment: edited to be more precise. Note that you need to modify one macro. If you would like to save the shortcut to the old macro and create a new one, go to *`Packages/Default.sublime-keymap`* and add *`{ "keys": ["shortcut"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/Default/New Macro.sublime-macro"} },`* to the content